# Using TLSharp How to get UserProfilePhoto's photo?

Tags: c#, telegram

I'm using [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) for dealing with really complicated [Telegram](http://telegram.org) API.

it's hard to understand how `xxxAbswww` types can be converted to `xxxwww` types which contains the real usable information!

I have the code below:

```
TLUser user = client.MakeAuthAsync("<user_number>", hash, code).Result;
```

how can I get the photo of authenticated user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agha Hamed,

Users' photo is accessible using 'userProfilePhoto' Telegram method and TLSharp didn't implemented this method.

But TLSharp provided some fascilities to implement other Telegram API methods. They says:

> You can call any method with help of SendRequestAsync function. For
>   example, send user typing method:

```
  //Create request 
  var req = new TLRequestSetTyping()
  {
    action = new TLSendMessageTypingAction(),
    peer = peer
  };

  //run request, and deserialize response to Boolean
  return await SendRequestAsync<Boolean>(req);
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to use SendRequestAsync function to do this.

Comment: thank you mard, by the way, I've created a charm app based on TLGenerator of Afshin Arani which generates based on TL language instead of JSON version of schema which is older version always, thus you can always use the latest version API which the Telegram official app uses. I upload it soon in the github. track me if you need.

Comment: We can help together. I will be thankful if you contact me by @Mahdioon313 at Telgram.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var photo = ((TLUserProfilePhoto)user.Photo);
var photoLocation = (TLFileLocation)photo.PhotoBig;

TLFile file = await client.GetFile(new TLInputFileLocation()
{
LocalId = photoLocation.LocalId,
Secret = photoLocation.Secret,
VolumeId = photoLocation.VolumeId
}, 1024 * 256);

//address to save pic 
string fileName = "D:\\Project\\user_profile.jpg";

using (var m = new MemoryStream(file.Bytes))
{
var img = Image.FromStream(m);

//pictureBox1.Image = img; //make a preview
img.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: "secret" is now missing from TLFileLocation (TLFileLocationToBeDeprecated)

Answer (score 0):

I dotn know why there is no example for TLSharp!
i am a newbe like you if you found the solution please post it here 
i just discovered that TLUser has a method named "photo"